# Creating a Map<Object,Array<Object>> in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am interested in creating the java equivalent of a Map data structure that looks as follows:

```
Map <Object --->  NSMutableArray of objects>
```

or

```
 Map<Object,Array<Object>>
```

Can anyone provide guidance on what would be the best way of doing this in objective c as I am fairly new to the language.

Comment: The text is a bit confusing, but it seems that this question is the other way around (what is the Objective-C equivalent of Java's Map), so it is not a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: Searching for "objective-c java map" led me immediately to the answer to that question. That page resolves the query from either starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c does not have typed collections. You just create NSMutableDictionary instance, and put NSMutableArray into the values.

Comment: Thus is not accurate. Foundation does not gave typed collections, but there is nothing preventing anyone from doing it.

Comment: @Soonts obj c only lets u use strings as the key... I'd like to have an object instance be the key. How can i do this?

Comment: @Aziz: Read the answer to the question that Josh linked to, and read the NSDictionary documentation. Keys can be not just strings, but any objects that conform to the NSCopying protocol.